# Is it possible to query by months in a whole year data

Tags: mysql, eloquent

Good day, I would like to ask if its possible to query in one all the data by month in a year.

desired data to display

```
    +---------+---------+------------------------+
    | Join Table                                 |
    +---------+---------+---+---+-----+----------+
    | acc_no  | acc_name|Jan|Feb|March| up to dec|
    +---------+---------+---+---+-----+----------+
    | 6220    | Sales   |
    | 6221    | Material|to be field with sum,
    | 6222    | Others  |group by acc_no,year,month
    |         |         |
    +---------+---------+------------------------+
```

so far what i have created is only for 1 month

```
    +-----------+--------------+
    | Join Table               |
    +---------+---------+------+
    | acc_no  | acc_name|Jan   |
    +---------+---------+------+
    | 6220    | Sales   |sum   |
    | 6221    | Material|data  |
    | 6222    | Others  |      |
    |         |         |      |
    +---------+---------+------+
```

**Controller**

```
        $year=2024;//temporary fixed var,my plan is on select option afterwards
        $january=1;//temporary fixed var,my plan is on select option afterwards
        $january_Balance= DB::table('general_ledgers')
        ->select('general_ledgers.acc_no', 'account_codes.account_name','general_ledgers.jnl_date',
           'general_ledgers.name_supplier_desc as desciption','general_ledgers.currency','general_ledgers.amount',
           'general_ledgers.fx_rate','general_ledgers.d_rate'


           )
        ->selectRaw("SUM(general_ledgers.amount) as total_amount")
        ->selectRaw("YEAR(general_ledgers.jnl_date) as year,MONTH(general_ledgers.jnl_date) as month")

        ->groupBy('account_codes.acc_no','year','month')
        ->whereYear('general_ledgers.jnl_date', $year)
        ->whereMonth('general_ledgers.jnl_date', $january)
        ->leftJoin('account_codes', 'account_codes.acc_no', '=', 'general_ledgers.acc_no')
        ->get();
        return Inertia::render('Accounting/TrialBalance',[
            'items' =>$january_Balance

        ]);
```

**Vue page**

```
                            <table class="table table-zebra ">
                                <!-- head -->
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Acc No.</th>
                                    <th>Account Name</th>
                                    <th>January</th>
                                    <th>February</th>
                                    <th>March</th>
                                    <th>April</th>
                                    <th>May</th>
                                    <th>June</th>
                                    <th>July</th>
                                    <th>August</th>
                                    <th>September</th>
                                    <th>October</th>
                                    <th>November</th>
                                    <th>December</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" >
                                        <td>{{ item.acc_no }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ item.account_name }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ item.total_amount }}</td>
                                        <td>for other months</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

so if possible i would like to do it on one query,the only thing i can think of is making multiple of the query per month but i would like to do it if possible in one query instead of making redundant query over and over per month

**edit Actual Data or tables**

```
+-----------+--------------+
| account codes            |
+---------+---------+------+
| acc_no  | acc_name|Desc  |
+---------+---------+------+
| 6220    | Sales   |some  |
| 6221    | Material|remark|
| 6222    | Others  |      |
|         |         |      |
+---------+---------+------+

+-----------+--------------+---------+--------+
| general_ledgers                    |        |
+---------+---------+------+---------+--------+
| id  | acc_id|Desc  |currency|amount+jnl_date|
+---------+---------+----------------+--------+
| 1   | 6220  |some  |JYP     |30000 |01/27/24|
| 2   | 6221  |remark|PHP     |-20000|02/2/24 |
| 3   | 6223  |      |JYP     |15000 |03/5/24 |
+---------+---------+----------------+--------+
```

Comment: can you show a sample of your table?

Comment: @Asgar it only returns me with one month only for january

Comment: I get it. I just want a sample of your table data. I mean the data structure with some data to work with

Comment: data type of the sum is double sample like 30000.0000

Comment: @Asgar oh sorry i'll get it

Comment: @Asgar i've included the table structure, sorry for the late response

Comment: I have added an answer below. Please check and update if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you did not mention your table structure with data, I have taken some references from the code you mentioned.
I am providing you with a raw query:

```
SELECT 
    general_ledgers.acc_no, 
    account_codes.account_name, 
    general_ledgers.jnl_date,
    general_ledgers.name_supplier_desc AS desciption,
    general_ledgers.currency,
    general_ledgers.amount,
    general_ledgers.fx_rate,
    general_ledgers.d_rate,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(general_ledgers.jnl_date)=2024 AND MONTH(general_ledgers.jnl_date) =1 THEN general_ledgers.amount ELSE 0 END) AS january,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(general_ledgers.jnl_date)=2024 AND MONTH(general_ledgers.jnl_date) =2 THEN general_ledgers.amount ELSE 0 END) AS february,
/*other months*/    
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(general_ledgers.jnl_date)=2024 AND MONTH(general_ledgers.jnl_date) =12 THEN general_ledgers.amount ELSE 0 END) AS december
FROM 
    general_ledgers
LEFT JOIN 
    account_codes ON account_codes.acc_no = general_ledgers.acc_no
WHERE general_ledgers.jnl_date BETWEEN '2024-01-01' AND '2024-12-31'
GROUP BY 
    general_ledgers.acc_no;
```

Or since we'll be fetching data for year 2024 only, you can also remove the `YEAR()` part and  use:

```
SELECT 
    general_ledgers.acc_no, 
    account_codes.account_name, 
    general_ledgers.jnl_date,
    general_ledgers.name_supplier_desc AS desciption,
    general_ledgers.currency,
    general_ledgers.amount,
    general_ledgers.fx_rate,
    general_ledgers.d_rate,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(general_ledgers.jnl_date) =1 THEN general_ledgers.amount ELSE 0 END) AS january,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(general_ledgers.jnl_date) =2 THEN general_ledgers.amount ELSE 0 END) AS february,
/*other months*/    
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(general_ledgers.jnl_date) =12 THEN general_ledgers.amount ELSE 0 END) AS december
FROM 
    general_ledgers
LEFT JOIN 
    account_codes ON account_codes.acc_no = general_ledgers.acc_no
WHERE general_ledgers.jnl_date BETWEEN '2024-01-01' AND '2024-12-31'
GROUP BY 
    general_ledgers.acc_no;
```

You can do something like this and get results for an entire 12 months in 1 query. You can work out the rest on your own.

Comment: THanks for the idea, I think I get the general idea on how this query works, thanks alot